# Is it possible to create custom memory-optimized GCE VMs?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Is it possible to create memory-optimized M1/M2 VMs in Google Cloud Engine with custom vCPU and Memory allocations?  The chart [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/vm-instance-pricing#m1_machine_types) lists pricing by vCPU / Memory allocated, suggesting it might support custom allocations.  But there is no option to create a custom memory-optimized VM in the VM creation UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not possible at the moment. Please have a look at the documentation [Creating a VM Instance with a custom machine type](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/creating-instance-with-custom-machine-type):

> **Custom machine types are available for general-purpose machine types only**; that is, when you create a custom machine type, you are
> effectively deploying a custom machine type from the E2, N2, N2D, or
> N1 machine type family.

So, it's expected that there's no such option via GCP Console UI.

Meanwhile, you can file a [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests) on the Google Public Issue tracker to change it.